# Unknown characters at the end of base64_decode result in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii

I'm using PHP IMAP functions to read emails from a remote server. While somebody sends an email through Gmail, the body shows ASCII encoding and as the message is in UTF-8, I had to use `base64_decode()` to convert it to acceptable result.
The remained problem is showing uknown characters at the end of returned string. It's something like this:

> این یک تست هست. ▯

I used different solutions to remove these characters but I was not able to do it. Do you have any practical solution?

Note: I used a variety of encoding conversion functions (like `iconv` , `utf8_encode`, etc.) to achieve the UTF-8 equivalent but none of them could not help me to convert ASCII to UTF-8.

Comment: the result you show is utf-8 encoding,  ends up with '▯', just filter ▯ character  with regex, no? or best use whitelist for allowed characters.

Comment: something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051684/check-if-utf-8-character-requires-maximum-three-bytes

Comment: I can not be sure what extra character might append to the final string. So your solution is not suitable in my mind

Comment: thats why you make a whitelist of allowed characters